# Is it possible to combine whereHas with 'or' queries?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to implement a filter system where, among other attributes and relationships, items are categorized. However, the challenge appears when combining OR queries with other filters using the regular and clause. The result grabs rows which I do not want and adds the or when the condition for that fails, thus polluting the final results with unwanted data.

```
<?php

class ProductSearch {

    public $builder;

    private $smartBuild; // this is the property I'm using to disable the alternation when other search parameters are present to avoid polluting their result

    function __construct( Builder $builder) {

        $this->builder = $builder;
    }

    public function applyFilterToQuery(array $filters) {

        $pollutants = ['subcategory', 'subcategory2', 'category'];

        $this->smartBuild = empty(array_diff( array_keys($filters), $pollutants)); // [ui=>9, mm=>4], [mm]

        foreach ($filters as $filterName => $value) {
            // dd($filters, $filterName );

            if (method_exists($this, $filterName) && !empty($value) )

                $this->$filterName( $value);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function location( $value) {

        $this->builder = $this->builder

        ->whereHas('store2', function($store) use ($value) {
            $store->where('state', $value);
        });
    }

    public function subcategory( $value) {

        $name = Subcategories::where('id', $value)->pluck('name');

        $this->builder = $this->builder->where('subcat_id', $value);

        if ($name->isNotEmpty() && $this->smartBuild) {

            $names = preg_split('/\W\s+/', $name[0]);

            if (!$names) $names = $name;

            foreach ($names as $value)

                $this->builder = $this->builder->orWhere('name', 'like', "%$value%");
        }
    }
}
```

You may observe from the above that making a request for categories searches products matching the category name. But on attempting to combine that alternate match with legitimate AND queries (in location for instance, the result tends to include matching locations OR matching names.
The desired result is ((matching name OR matching category) AND matching location). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar situation like this few days ago about User and Posts.

Needed a list of posts which user has commented or participated in and which user owns.

So I did following on User model

```
//Get user created post or if user has participated in the post
$queryString->where(function ($query) use ($user_id) {
    return $query->whereHas('participants', function ($q) use ($user_id) {
        $q->where('user_id', $user_id);
    })->orWhere('id', $user_id);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi. I'm trying to adapt your solution to my situation but can't seem to have much success. What I understand you did is wrapping the AND queries in closures, then directly calling the OR queries on the builder. So I modified the class in OP to this https://pastebin.com/GkBw4yjm . It still doesn't work for me